# Responsive Web Development Issue - Overlapping elements

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive

I have an issue with a website I'm developing, pure HTML, CSS and JS (FullPage.js) so far.

My aim was that when the width is a certain size, all of the elements center to the page and the page overflows using fullpage.js

[What I see at 320x668 resolution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nO6to.png)

[After applying Flexbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9C6x.png)

[image: Image of text centering on the left]

Issues I'm having so far are as follows, elements are not centering as expected and it is overlapping.

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) 
{

.s2 
{
    
 display: flex;
 background-color: aqua; 
 flex-direction: column; 
 justify-content: center;

}
    
#abouttextdiv 
{
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%;
}

#aboutTitle
{
    
    font-family: fantasy;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 10px;
    left: 25%;
    
}

#makingtext
{   
    
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 20px;
    left: 25%;
}

#sparkletext
{
    
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    font-family: 'Pacifico';
    background: rgb(255, 112, 184);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    width: 100%;
    
}

#beach_icon
{
    
    position: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    font-size: 48px;

}

#camera_icon
{
    
    position: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    font-size: 48px;
    
}


.aboutimagediv
{   
    
    display: none;
            
}

#aboutParagraphOne
{
    
    position: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    font-size: 2vh;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 20px;

}

#aboutParagraphTwo
{
    
    position: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    font-size: 2vh;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    width: 100%;

}

#aboutParagraphThree
{
    
    position: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    left: 50%;  
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    font-size: 2vh;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    width: 100%;
}

}
```

```html
<section class="section s2" id="aboutUs">
  <h1 id="aboutTitle">About Us</h1>
  <div class="aboutimagediv">
    <img src="Media/Images/About_Page/hennaAndNails.jpg" alt="Image of Woman's nails with Glitter and Henna" class="aboutimage">
  </div>
  <div class="abouttextdiv">
    <h2 id="makingtext">Making your day </h2>
    <h2 id = "sparkletext">Sparkle</h2>
    <!--<p id = "tagline">We run booths at events all around County</p><!-->
    <!-- <p id="aboutParagraphOne">As a small business in Area,<br> we love all things glitter and Shine</p><!-->
    <!-- <p id="aboutParagraphThree">You can find us at all the best events, <br> festivals and parties around Area!</p><!-->
    <p id="aboutParagraphOne">Our main aim is to sparkle and shine where ever we go. <br> Creating happiness, laughter and a fun vibe to every second we are with you. From small events, large events or even a home event we are here to cater to your needs. </p>
    <i class="material-icons" id="camera_icon">camera_alt</i>
    <p id="aboutParagraphTwo">Our passion lies with making you <br> feel as great as you look </p>
    <i class="material-icons" id="beach_icon">beach_access</i>
    <p id="aboutParagraphThree">Parties, festivals, fetes and carnivals wedding we cover them all. <br> Pampering, at your home or my home salon includes nail services to both fingers and toes. Bump Paintings can be accommodated at your home for your comfort or at my home salon if you're planning a surprise.</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

If I do not put the "About Us" text as `absolute` and I give it a `transform(-50%,-50%)` it seems to force it to the left of the screen instead of the dead center as I thought it would.

If someone could help me uncover what I'm missing I would appreciate it. I understand this might seem basic, but my searches around W3CSchools and similar resources have not eased my understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So is this what you are trying to do.

[image]

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


/* i changed the query from 600 to 900 so it can show once you run this sinppet
don't forget to change it to 600px once you copy the code
*/

@media only screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  .s2 {
    /* display: flex; */
    background-color: aqua;
    /* flex-direction: column; */
    /* justify-content: center; */
    height: 100%;
  }
  .abouttextdiv {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
  #aboutTitle {
    font-family: fantasy;
    /* width: 100%; */
    /* display: flex; */
    /* flex-direction: column; */
    padding: 10px;
    /* left: 25%; */
    text-align: center;
  }
  #makingtext {
    /* display: flex; */
    /* flex-direction: column; */
    text-align: center;
    /* width: 100%; */
    padding-top: 20px;
    /* left: 25%; */
  }
  #sparkletext {
    /* display: flex; */
    /* flex-direction: column; */
    /* transform: translate(-50%, -50%); */
    font-family: 'Pacifico';
    background: #ff70b8;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .icon-holder {
    text-align: center;
  }
  #beach_icon {
    /* position: flex; */
    /* flex-direction: column; */
    font-size: 28px;
  }
  #camera_icon {
    /* position: flex; */
    /* flex-direction: column; */
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    font-size: 28px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .aboutimagediv {
    display: none;
  }
  .abouttextdiv {
    text-align: center;
  }
  .aboutParagraphOne {
    /* position: flex; */
    /* flex-direction: column; */
    /* transform: translate(-50%, -50%); */
    font-size: 2vh;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
  }
  .aboutParagraphTwo {
    /* position: flex; */
    /* flex-direction: column; */
    font-size: 2vh;
    /* transform: translate(-50%, -50%); */
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .aboutParagraphThree {
    /* position: flex; */
    /* flex-direction: column; */
    /* left: 50%; */
    /* transform: translate(-50%, -50%); */
    font-size: 2vh;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-1PKOgIY59xJ8Co8+NE6FZ+LOAZKjy+KY8iq0G4B3CyeY6wYHN3yt9PW0XpSriVlkMXe40PTKnXrLnZ9+fkDaog==" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<section class="section s2" id="aboutUs">
  <h1 id="aboutTitle">About Us</h1>
  <div class="aboutimagediv">
    <img src="assets/images/image.jpg" height="200" width="200" alt="Image of Woman's nails with Glitter and Henna" class="aboutimage">
  </div>
  <div class="abouttextdiv">
    <h2 id="makingtext">Making your day </h2>
    <h2 id="sparkletext">Sparkle</h2>
    <!--<p id = "tagline">We run booths at events all around County</p><!-->
    <!-- <p id="aboutParagraphOne">As a small business in Area,<br> we love all things glitter and Shine</p><!-->
    <!-- <p id="aboutParagraphThree">You can find us at all the best events, <br> festivals and parties around Area!</p><!-->
    <p class="aboutParagraphOne">Our main aim is to sparkle and shine where ever we go. <br> Creating happiness, laughter and a fun vibe to every second we are with you. From small events, large events or even a home event we are here to cater to your needs. </p>
    <div class="icon-holder">
      <i class="fas fa-umbrella" id="camera_icon">camera_alt</i>

    </div>
    <p id="aboutParagraphTwo">Our passion lies with making you <br> feel as great as you look </p>
    <div class="icon-holder">
      <i class="fas fa-camera" id="beach_icon">beach_access</i>
    </div>
    <p class="aboutParagraphThree">Parties, festivals, fetes and carnivals wedding we cover them all. <br> Pampering, at your home or my home salon includes nail services to both fingers and toes. Bump Paintings can be accommodated at your home for your comfort or at my home salon
      if you're planning a surprise.</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

If that didn't work please let me know.

Comment: Hi Ahmed, thanks for your feedback. I have applied something similar to this, code outside of the Media Queries were affecting the media queries page, and those transform queries were causing issues. It appears to be working okay now!
I

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using CSS Flexbox? Just adding the Flex display property with flex-direction: column to your sections and divs would give you the responsive vertical layout you want

Comment: Does this need to be applied to divs outside of the section too?
I have applied the properties stated but it has just moved things around from the looks of it
I have updated the post with what changes after I apply the property. I will also do some research on flexbox

Answer (score 0):

```css
@media only screen 
  and (max-width: 600px) {
  
    #aboutUs {
      text-align: center;
    }
  
    #aboutTitle {
      font-family: fantasy;
    }
    
    #makingtext {
      width: 100%;
    }

    #sparkletext {
      font-family: 'Pacifico';
      background: rgb(255, 112, 184);
      -webkit-background-clip: text;
      -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    }

    .s2 {
      background-color: aqua
    }

    #beach_icon {
      font-size: 124px;
    }

    #camera_icon {
      padding-bottom: 20px;
      font-size: 72px;
     }

    .aboutimagediv {   
      display: none;
    }

    #aboutParagraphOne {
      font-size: 2.5vh;
      padding-bottom: 20px;
    }

    #aboutParagraphTwo {
      font-size: 2.5vh;
      text-align: center;
      padding-bottom: 10px;
      padding-top: 20px;
    }

    #aboutParagraphThree {
      font-size: 2.5vh;
      padding-bottom: 10px;
      padding-top: 20px;
    }
}
```

```html
<section class="section s2" id="aboutUs">
  <h1 id="aboutTitle">About Us</h1>
  <div class="aboutimagediv">
    <img src="Media/Images/About_Page/hennaAndNails.jpg" alt="Image of Woman's nails with Glitter and Henna" class="aboutimage">
  </div>
  <div class="abouttextdiv">
    <h2 id="makingtext">Making your day </h2>
    <h2 id = "sparkletext">Sparkle</h2>
    <!--<p id = "tagline">We run booths at events all around County</p><!-->
    <!-- <p id="aboutParagraphOne">As a small business in Area,<br> we love all things glitter and Shine</p><!-->
    <!-- <p id="aboutParagraphThree">You can find us at all the best events, <br> festivals and parties around Area!</p><!-->
    <p id="aboutParagraphOne">Our main aim is to sparkle and shine where ever we go. <br> Creating happiness, laughter and a fun vibe to every second we are with you. From small events, large events or even a home event we are here to cater to your needs. </p>
    <i class="material-icons" id="camera_icon">camera_alt</i>
    <p id="aboutParagraphTwo">Our passion lies with making you <br> feel as great as you look </p>
    <i class="material-icons" id="beach_icon">beach_access</i>
    <p id="aboutParagraphThree">Parties, festivals, fetes and carnivals wedding we cover them all. <br> Pampering, at your home or my home salon includes nail services to both fingers and toes. Bump Paintings can be accommodated at your home for your comfort or at my home salon if you're planning a surprise.</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

centering is not an issue if you remove all the static postion which overwrites the centering. Also display blocks... however it will not fix the issue that 124px font-size is to large for screens that small.

Comment: Hi there, the 124px font-size is just for an icon so I can test if the media query was working as intended.

Comment: I have since changed it, and also removed previous CSS styling outside of the media queries. 
This has nearly fixed it, however all of the text is pushed to the left-side of the screen, as if the left-side is the center.
I will provide an example in the original post, and update the code

Answer (score 0):

The main problem seems to be that you use `transform: translate(-50%, -50%);` and `left: 50%` on several elements, which will (also) move them up vertically and make them overlap that way. Erase those settings, or if you already have similar `transform` settings for non-mobile screen sizes, "neutralize" them by changeing them to `left: 0` and `transform: none`.